# How to fix the directoiry in python

Tags: python

I have this problem while I am running my python code. Can anyone help debug please

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)

NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'runs\MarlGrid-3Agent15x15-v0/a3c_seed-1_lr-0.0001_tmax-20_workers-16_ms-512_ae_type-_2022-09-17_09:32'

Comment: Welcomet to SO. Seeing your code would help. Actually, if you read your code once again, you'd probably find solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is pretty explicit, the name you choose for the folder is not valid

Comment: And to be more specific, you cannot have `:` as part of a folder or file name in Windows.